# Dropped Capability Not Removing Permissions

Tags: linux, linux-capabilities

I have built a C++ binary and called `setcap cap_net_raw,cap_setpcap+pe` on it, granting the `NET_RAW` and `SET_PCAP` capabilities. I have verified these capabilities are present in the binary by successfully creating a `socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, ...)`. Without calling `setcap`, the `socket` function returns a permission error.

For security reasons, I'd like to drop the `NET_RAW` capability once I've acquired the socket. This is why I also set the `SET_PCAP` capability, so I can call `prctl(PR_CAPBSET_DROP, CAP_NET_RAW, ...)`. After making this call, `prctl(PR_CAPBSET_READ, CAP_NET_RAW, ...)` indicates I no longer have the `NET_RAW` permission. *HOWEVER*, I can still call `socket(..., SOCK_RAW, ...)` successfully! Even if I close the existing raw socket, I can later still create a new one.

Is there something else I need to do to remove my process's permissions to create a new raw socket?

Comment: The bset is only consulted when a program calls exec*(). If you are not doing that, you need to drop the bits from your permitted and effective sets to lose this privilege.